# Sampling distribution

Tags: node.js, math, probability

Assume I have some distribution defined by probabilities like the following `[0.1, 0.6, 0.2, 0.1]`. The sum of probabilities equals 1. I wonder how I can sample this distribution, such that the sampling will follow the distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on whether your distribution is discrete or continuous. For the continuous case you have to interpolate linearly between two values. Here is the pseudocode

1. Let `u` be a random number between `0` and `1`
2. Let `i` such that `p[i] <= u <= p[i+1]`
3. Return `(x[i+1] - x[i]) / (p[i+1] - p[i]) * (u - p[i]) + x[i]`

Note that in 2 there could be no such `i` because of two reasons: (a) `u < p[1]` or (b) `p[n] < u` (I'm assuming `1`-based arrays). In case (a) return `x[1]` in case (b) `x[n]`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the PRNG of Node.JS follows a uniform distribution a simple solution could be this one:

```
var v = Math.random(); // return a number between 0 and 1

if(v < 0.1)
    // first value
else if(v < 0.7) // (0.1 + 0.6)
    // second value
else if(v < 0.9) // (0.1 + 0.6 + 0.2)
    // third value
else
    // forth value
```

This question has been already answered here (the proposed solution is more general since they proposed a function that can accept an array of probabilities): 
[distributional sampling in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22863565/distributional-sampling-in-node-js)

Comment: can you provide with intuition or give some reference why this is the right way to do so?